# How to read specific lines alone from an input file in Fortran 90? (Preferably in a loop)

Tags: loops, variables, fortran

This is the input file.

[image]

In this I would like to read 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 into the following variable like this:

```
read(25,*) nodein
```

The other values will need to be referenced in this manner: the 1 0 0 sequence should be referenced to the other three variables.

```
do irest = 1,node
read(25,*)  rest(3*i-2),rest(3*i-1),rest(3*i)
end do
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, with a couple of exceptions which I shall mention below, each time you execute a Fortran I/O statement it goes on to the next line, technically called a "Record". You seem to understand this from your second code fragment. So using this knowledge can you see why

```
do irest = 1,node
   read(25,*) nodein
   read(25,*) rest(3*i-2),rest(3*i-1),rest(3*i)
end do
```

will do what you want?

The exceptions are non-advancing I/O and stream I/O, neither of which apply here.

While I'm here it would be better if you could provide a complete program to show what you are confused about - it's simple enough here but in many cases it makes it much easier to understand the issues. And out of curiosity why are you simulating a 2D array for `rest`, that would seem a much more natural way to index it!